# How to delete half of the data from notepad file quickly

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I have a large notepad file and want to delete the first half of the data. I am at the midpoint now, the point at which I must do a trick to delete all the data before it. What command can help me do this? If I just do it with the backspace, it will take forever!
thanks!

Comment: At mid point, press Ctrl + Shift + Home - to select till the beginning. Then press 'Delete' or 'Backspace'.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At your mid-position, Hold <kbd>shift</kbd>, press <kbd>page up</kbd>. It will select starting with your position all the way to the top. 
then press <kbd>delete</kbd> key.

If the last page (top most one will not select), keep pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> and use `up-key` the select the rest of it.

<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> home method usually works, but can be bugged in anything is bound to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.

Comment: And how much time I should press pageUp? This is not a good way to mark from point to the top or bottom!

Comment: I found many situations of users where ctrl key was bound to other functions (and not usable for the C-S-home combo), thats why I offered the alternative.

Comment: This is too heavy alternative. In such case is much easy to use mouse. And I am sorry, but Ctrl key is so much used so reassign it can be stupid!

Comment: Well, users do very unexpected things. :D Anyway I'd recommend using an actual editor, notepad is very limited when it comes to text edit. A good editor will also have things line select from line no 2 line no & other similar things. Even an ancient MSDOS editor is more advanced than notepad.

Answer (score 6):

Click on the point where is the middle, then

```
Ctrl+Shift+Home, then Del
```

if you want to delete from midpoint to the top

```
Ctrl+Shift+End, then Del
```

if you want to delete from midpoint to the bottom